# number divide by zero is hardware exception

Tags: c++, c, exception, assembly, divide-by-zero

I have learnt during C++ exceptional handling that number divide by zero is a hardware exception. Can anybody explain it why it is called hardware exception

Answer (score 7):

Because it is not an exception in the C++ sense.  Usually, in the C++ world, we use the word "hardware trap", to avoid any ambiguity, but "hardware exception" can also be used.  Basically, the hardware triggers something which will cause you to land in the OS.

And not all systems will generate a hardware trap for divide by 0.  I've worked on one where you just got the largest possible value as a result, and kept on.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ Standard itself considers divide by zero to be *Undefined Behaviour*, but as usual an implementation can provide *Implementation Defined Behaviour* if it likes.

C++20 stipulations:

> 7.1.4 If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the **behavior is undefined**. [Note: **Treatment of division by zero**, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all floating-point exceptions **varies among machines**, and is **sometimes adjustable** by a library function.— end note

Typically in practice, your CPU will check for divide by zero, and historically different CPU manufacturers have used different terminology for the CPU behaviour that results: some call it an "interrupt", others a "trap", or "signal", or "exception", or "fault", or "abort".  CPU designers don't tend to care about - or avoid clashes with - anything but their hardware and assembly language terminology....

Regardless, even if called a "hardware exception", it's nothing to do with C++ exceptions in the `try`/`catch` sense.

On an Intel for example, a divide by zero will result in the CPU spontaneously saving a minimum of registers on the stack, then calling a function whose address must have been placed in a specific memory address beforehand.

It's up to the OS/executable to pick/override with some useful behaviour, and while some C++ compilers do specifically support interception of these events and generation of C++ Exceptions, it's not a feature mentioned by the C++ Standard, nor widely portable.  The general expectation is that you'll either write a class that checks consistently, or perform ad-hoc checks before divisions that might fail.

Comment: Divide by 0 has been UB in C and in C++ for a lot longer than C++20, in case anyone was wondering if this is new with C++20.  And yes, UB doesn't mean "guaranteed to fault".  Some CPUs don't have exceptions for integer division, e.g. ARM.  [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46378104) has an example.  (In this case signed overflow instead of division by 0.)

Answer (score 3):

This is a hardware exception because it's detected by CPU.

Your code in c/c++ or any other language is converted to CPU commands and then executed by CPU. So only CPU can find out you divided by zero

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your processor if you get an exception or not.  Fixed point and floating point also are different or can be.  The floating point spec, to be compliant, has both an exception and non-exception solution for devide by zero.  If the fpu has that exception disabled then you would get the "properly signed infinity" otherwise you get an exception and the result is instead a nan or something like that I dont have the spec handy.

The programmers reference manual for a particular processor should hopefully discuss fixed point divide by zero behavior if the processor has a divide at all.  If not then it is a soft divide and then it is up to the compiler library as to what it does (calls a divide by zero handler for example).

It would be called a hardware exception in general because the hardware is detecting the problem, and the hardware does something as a result.  Same thing when you have other problems like mmu access faults, data aborts, prefetch aborts, etc.  hardware exception because it is an exception handled by hardware, generally...

Answer (score 0):

Because, if it is checked, then it is checked and raised by the hardware. Specifically, the Arithmetic-Logic Unit (ALU) of your CPU will check for 0 as divider and generate an appropriate interrupt to signal the exception.

Otherwise, you would have to explicitely check for 0 in the assembler source code.

Edit: Note that this apply to integer division only, since floating point division has specific states to signal a division by zero.

Comment: And also only if it is an integer division. A floating point division will not cause the same behavior.

Comment: @PMF floating point is handled by the FPU, not by the ALU. Anyway, I will add a pointer.