# Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, arm64, floating-point-exceptions

I have an assignment of expaining some *seemingly* strange behaviors of C code (running on x86). I can easily complete everything else but this one has really confused me.

> Code snippet 1 outputs `-2147483648`
>
> ```
> int a = 0x80000000;
> int b = a / -1;
> printf("%d\n", b);
> ```

> Code snippet 2 outputs nothing, and gives a `Floating point exception`
>
> ```
> int a = 0x80000000;
> int b = -1;
> int c = a / b;
> printf("%d\n", c);
> ```

I well know the reason for the result of Code Snippet 1 (`1 + ~INT_MIN == INT_MIN`), but I can't quite understand how can integer division by -1 generate FPE, nor can I reproduce it on my Android phone (AArch64, GCC 7.2.0). Code 2 just output the same as Code 1 without any exceptions. Is it a hidden <s>bug</s> feature of x86 processor?

The assignment didn't tell anything else (including CPU architecture), but since the whole course is based on a desktop Linux distro, you can safely assume it's a modern x86.

---

**Edit**: I contacted my friend and he tested the code on Ubuntu 16.04 (Intel Kaby Lake, GCC 6.3.0). The result was consistent with whatever the assignment stated (Code 1 output the said thing and Code 2 crashed with FPE).

Comment: "I have an assignment of explaining some UBs of C" is a mistake. The only way to explain it is to say absolutely *anything* can happen.

Comment: @paxdiablo Edited the question. It's not a UB but CPU architecture dependent behavior.

Comment: @iBug: The architecture should be mentioned in the question (which is then not about C, but about machine code obtained by some particular C compiler on some particular machine). On x86-64 integer overflows on Linux may give a `SIGFPE`

Comment: I certainly won't be surprised if your first snippet is compiled to a negation rather than a division. It's a simple peephole optimization.

Comment: @T.C. Your comment is the right answer.

Comment: You actually don't know the result in case 1, neither in case 2, as both lead you to **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR**, which means that you can know what your implementation does.... but you'll never know what **any** implementation which is standard compliant will give.

Comment: @ibug, that's not a architecture dependent behaviour.  On signed integer overflow (that happens in both cases) the result of your expression is **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR** and not **implementation defined behaviour**.  Read the standard, please.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is not a bug elsewhere, but in your code.  If you commit to U.B. you are on your own risk.  Don't bother about some bug elsewhere.  Nobody is forced to implement some kind of U.B. in any coherent or definite way.  That's what U.B.  means.

Comment: you are changing the sign to a value that has no positive counterpart (`INT_MIN` has no positive counterpart) so _you overflow._  And using `signed` integer overflow is U.B. in ANSI-C.  So **it is U.B.** and so, anything can happen (even some strange behavior like the observed one).  You should consider using that value (`INT_MIN`, in two's complement architectures that extend the value of `INT_MIN` from the minimum specified values in the standard) with care.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are four things going on here:

- `gcc -O0` behaviour explains the difference between your two versions: `idiv` vs. `neg`.  (While `clang -O0` happens to compile them both with `idiv`).  And why you get this even with compile-time-constant operands.
- x86 [`idiv`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html) faulting behaviour vs. behaviour of the division instruction on ARM
- If integer math results in a signal being delivered, POSIX require it to be SIGFPE: [On which platforms does integer divide by zero trigger a floating point exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262572/on-which-platforms-does-integer-divide-by-zero-trigger-a-floating-point-exceptio/37266507#37266507)  But POSIX *doesn't* require trapping for any particular integer operation.  (This is why it's allowed for x86 and ARM to be different).

  The Single Unix Specification [defines SIGFPE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) as "Erroneous arithmetic operation".  It's confusingly named after floating point, but in a normal system with the FPU in its default state, only integer math will raise it.  On x86, only integer division.  On MIPS, a compiler could use [`add` instead of `addu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634110/difference-between-add-and-addu) for signed math, so you could get traps on signed add overflow.  ([gcc uses `addu` even for signed](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27int+add(int+a,+int+b)+%7B+return+a%2Bb%3B+%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.41535396579329,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.58464603420673,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), but an undefined-behaviour detector might use `add`.)
- C Undefined Behaviour rules (signed overflow, and division specifically) which let gcc emit code which can trap in that case.

---

gcc with no options is the same as **`gcc -O0`**.

> `-O0`
> Reduce compilation time and **make debugging produce the expected results**. This is the default.

This explains the difference between your two versions:

Not only does `gcc -O0` not try to optimize, it actively *de-optimizes* to make asm that independently implements each C statement within a function.  This allows [`gdb`'s `jump` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116632/is-it-possible-to-jump-skip-in-gdb-debugger/46043760#46043760) to work safely, letting you jump to a different line within the function and act like you're really jumping around in the C source.  [Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point) explains more about how and why `-O0` compiles the way it does.

It also can't assume anything about variable values between statements, because you can change variables with `set b = 4`.  This is obviously catastrophically bad for performance, which is why `-O0` code runs several times slower than normal code, and why [optimizing for `-O0` specifically is total nonsense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000917/c-loop-optimization-help-for-final-assignment/32001196#32001196).  It also makes `-O0` asm output [really noisy and hard for a human to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output), because of all the storing/reloading, and lack of even the most obvious optimizations.

```
int a = 0x80000000;
int b = -1;
  // debugger can stop here on a breakpoint and modify b.
int c = a / b;        // a and b have to be treated as runtime variables, not constants.
printf("%d\n", c);
```

I put your code inside functions **on the Godbolt [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27int+nofault()+%7B%0A++++int+a+%3D+0x80000000%3B%0A++++int+c+%3D+a+/+-1%3B%0A++++return+c%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+x86_fault()+%7B%0A++++int+a+%3D+0x80000000%3B%0A++++int+b+%3D+-1%3B%0A++++int+c+%3D+a+/+b%3B%0A++++return+c%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23if+0%0Aint+negate_intmin(void)+%7B%0A++++return+-+(int)0x80000000%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+another+example+of+undefined+behaviour%0Aint+*local_address(int+a)+%7B%0A++++return+%26a%3B%0A%7D%0Avoid+more_ub()+%7B%0A++++int+*p+%3D+local_address(4)%3B%0A++++*p+%3D+2%3B%0A%7D%0A//+gcc+-O3+compiles+this+to+a+load+of+absolute+address+0%0A//+then+UD2+(illegal+instruction)%0A%23endif%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:25.75485544842309,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g630,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu11+-O0%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM64+gcc+6.3.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:34.08818878175642,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-std%3Dgnu11+-O0%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:32.57847788491026,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu11+-O0%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)** to get the asm for those statements.

To evaluate `a/b`, `gcc -O0` has to emit code to reload `a` and `b` from memory, and not make any assumptions about their value.

But **with `int c = a / -1;`, you can't change the `-1` with a debugger**, so gcc can and does implement that statement the same way it would implement `int c = -a;`, with an x86 `neg  eax` or AArch64 `neg  w0, w0` instruction, surrounded by a load(a)/store(c).  On ARM32, it's a `rsb r3, r3, #0` (reverse-subtract: `r3 = 0 - r3`).

However, clang5.0 `-O0` doesn't do that optimization.  It still uses `idiv` for `a / -1`, so both versions will fault on x86 with clang.  Why does gcc "optimize" at all?  See [Disable all optimization options in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278757/disable-all-optimization-options-in-gcc/33284629#33284629).  gcc always transforms through an internal representation, and -O0 is just the minimum amount of work needed to produce a binary.  It doesn't have a "dumb and literal" mode that tries to make the asm as much like the source as possible.

---

#### x86 `idiv` vs. AArch64 `sdiv`:

**x86-64:**

```
    # int c = a / b  from x86_fault()
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdq                                 # dividend sign-extended into edx:eax
    idiv    DWORD PTR [rbp-8]           # divisor from memory
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax     # store quotient
```

Unlike `imul r32,r32`, there's no 2-operand `idiv` that doesn't have a dividend upper-half input.  Anyway, not that it matters; gcc is only using it with `edx` = copies of the sign bit in `eax`, so it's really doing a 32b / 32b => 32b quotient + remainder.  [As documented in Intel's manual](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html), `idiv` raises #DE on:

- divisor = 0
- The signed result (quotient) is too large for the destination.

Overflow can easily happen if you use the full range of divisors, e.g. for `int result = long long / int` with a single 64b / 32b => 32b division.  But gcc can't do that optimization because it's not allowed to make code that would fault instead of following the C integer promotion rules and doing a 64-bit division and *then* truncating to `int`.  It also [doesn't optimize even in cases where the divisor is known to be large enough that it couldn't `#DE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248230/msvc-inline-asm-to-gcc#46291899)

When doing 32b / 32b division (with `cdq`), the only input that can overflow is `INT_MIN / -1`.  The "correct" quotient is a 33-bit signed integer, i.e. positive `0x80000000` with a leading-zero sign bit to make it a positive 2's complement signed integer.  Since this doesn't fit in `eax`, `idiv` raises a `#DE` exception.  The kernel then delivers `SIGFPE`.

**AArch64:**

```
    # int c = a / b  from x86_fault()  (which doesn't fault on AArch64)
    ldr     w1, [sp, 12]
    ldr     w0, [sp, 8]          # 32-bit loads into 32-bit registers
    sdiv    w0, w1, w0           # 32 / 32 => 32 bit signed division
    str     w0, [sp, 4]
```

ARM hardware division instructions don't raise exceptions for divide by zero or for `INT_MIN/-1` overflow.  Nate Eldredge commented:

> The full ARM architecture reference manual states that UDIV or SDIV, when dividing by zero, simply return zero as the result, "without any indication that the division by zero occurred" (C3.4.8 in the Armv8-A version). No exceptions and no flags - if you want to catch divide by zero, you have to write an explicit test. Likewise, signed divide of `INT_MIN` by `-1` returns `INT_MIN` with no indication of the overflow.

[AArch64 `sdiv` documentation](https://developer.arm.com/docs/100069/0607/a64-general-instructions/sdiv) doesn't mention any exceptions.

However, software implementations of integer division may raise: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4061.html.  (gcc uses a library call for division on ARM32 by default, unless you set a -mcpu that has HW division.)

---

### C Undefined Behaviour.

As [PSkocik explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378104/why-does-integer-division-by-1-negative-one-result-in-fpe/46378352#46378352), `INT_MIN` / `-1` is undefined behaviour in C, like all signed integer overflow.  **This allows compilers to use hardware division instructions on machines like x86 without checking for that special case.**  If it had to *not* fault, unknown inputs would require run-time compare-and branch checks, and nobody wants C to require that.

---

More about the consequences of UB:

**With optimization enabled**, the compiler can assume that `a` and `b` still have their set values when `a/b` runs.  It can then see the program has undefined behaviour, and thus can do whatever it wants.  gcc chooses to produce `INT_MIN` like it would from `-INT_MIN`.

On a 2's complement system, the most-negative number is its own negative.  This is a nasty corner-case for 2's complement, because it means `abs(x)` can still be negative.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number

```
int x86_fault() {
    int a = 0x80000000;
    int b = -1;
    int c = a / b;
    return c;
}
```

compile to this with `gcc6.3 -O3` for x86-64

```
x86_fault:
    mov     eax, -2147483648
    ret
```

but `clang5.0 -O3` compiles to (with no warning even with -Wall -Wextra`):

```
x86_fault:
    ret
```

Undefined Behaviour really is totally undefined.  Compilers can do whatever they feel like, including returning whatever garbage was in `eax` on function entry, or loading a NULL pointer and an illegal instruction.  e.g. with gcc6.3 -O3 for x86-64:

```
int *local_address(int a) {
    return &a;
}

local_address:
    xor     eax, eax     # return 0
    ret

void foo() {
    int *p = local_address(4);
    *p = 2;
}

 foo:
   mov     DWORD PTR ds:0, 0     # store immediate 0 into absolute address 0
   ud2                           # illegal instruction
```

Your case with `-O0` didn't let the compilers see the UB at compile time, so you got the "expected" asm output.

See also [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) (the same LLVM blog post that Basile linked).

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Did I make it too long and rambling?  I didn't want to assume very much starting knowledge, but that made it into a long answer :/

Comment: I checked the assembly output and immediately knew what was happening when I saw `a/-1;` was compiled into `negl %eax` while `a/b` was compiled to `cltd; idivl %ebx`. Thank you for your long explanation and patience!

Comment: The full ARM architecture reference manual states that UDIV or SDIV, when dividing by zero, simply return zero as the result, "without any indication that the division by zero occurred" (C3.4.8 in the Armv8-A version).  No exceptions and no flags - if you want to catch divide by zero, you have to write an explicit test.  Likewise, signed divide of `INT_MIN` by `-1` returns `INT_MIN` with no indication of the overflow.

Answer (score 7):

Signed `int` division in two's complement is undefined if:

1. the divisor is zero, OR
2. the dividend is `INT_MIN` (==`0x80000000` if `int` is `int32_t`) and the divisor is `-1` (in two's complement,
   `-INT_MIN > INT_MAX`, which causes integer overflow, which is undefined behavior in C)

([https://www.securecoding.cert.org](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT33-C.+Ensure+that+division+and+remainder+operations+do+not+result+in+divide-by-zero+errors) recommends wrapping integer operations in functions that check for such edge cases)

Since you're invoking undefined behavior by breaking rule 2, anything can happen, and as it happens, this particular anything on your platform happens to be an FPE signal being generated by your processor.

Answer (score 2):

With [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) very [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) things could happen, and sometimes they do happen.

Your question has no sense in C (read [Lattner on UB](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)). But you could get the assembler code (e.g. produced by `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S`) and care about machine code behavior.

On x86-64 with Linux integer overflow (and also integer division by zero, IIRC) gives a `SIGFPE` signal. See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

BTW, on PowerPC integer division by zero is rumored to give -1 at the machine level (but some C compilers generate extra code to test that case).

The code in your question is undefined behavior in C. The generated assembler code has some defined behavior (depends upon the [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) and processor).

<sup>(the assignment is done to make you read more about UB, notably [Lattner 's blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), which you should *absolutely* read)</sup>

Comment: Only `gcc -O0` explains the observed behaviour.  Anything other than `-O0` will do constant propagation at compile time.  But `-O0` has to make code that still implements the C source if you change the values of variables at runtime with a debugger.  e.g. it can't optimize away the reload and x86 `idiv` in the 2nd version, because `int b = -1;` might not still be `-1` in the next statement.

Comment: Only integer overflow *from division* raises SIGFPE on x86-64 Linux.  (Actually IDK what happens if you scatter [`into`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/INT%20n:INTO:INT%203.html) instructions after signed addition / subtraction / whatever; the `#OF` exception might be handled the same as a `#DE` exception by the kernel.)  But the compiler doesn't do that, so division is the only integer operation that ever traps in C on x86-64.

Comment: Wrote that up into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

On x86 if you divide by *actually using* the [idiv](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_137.html) operation (which is not really necessary for constant arguments, not even for variables-known-to-be-constant, but it happened anyway), `INT_MIN / -1` is one of the cases that results in #DE (divide error). It's really a special case of the quotient being out of range, in general that is possible because `idiv` divides an extra-wide dividend by the divisor, so many combinations cause overflow - but `INT_MIN / -1` is the only case that isn't a div-by-0 that you can normally access from higher level languages since they typically do not expose the extra-wide-dividend capabilities.

Linux annoyingly maps the #DE to SIGFPE, which has probably confused everyone who dealt with it the first time.

Comment: POSIX requires `SIGFPE` if there's a signal at all.  :/  But on Linux / GNU systems, apparently you can distinguish between `FPE_INTDIV_TRAP` and actual FP causes: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Error-Signals.html.  See my answer for an explanation of why `idiv` is necessary with `gcc -O0` for one but not both cases.