# Does -O0 in gcc include any optimization?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I have been searching about that all over the web. The only thing i found is people saying that it, in fact, does some optimization, but they dont specify which one.

Thanks

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Checking this documentation, there are some optimizations enabled by default in -O0: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: @Victor Where do you see that "some optimizations are enabled by default in -O0" ? I see nothing about that in the doc (though it does not say that all optimizations are disabled but just "most"). If if so which one would be enabled?

Comment: Related: [Disable all optimization options in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33278757) /  [How to turn off all optimizations in GCC](//stackoverflow.com/q/20248424) - GCC does [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41183935) at `-O0` along with some other stuff inside an expression, although it doesn't do constant-propagation between statements so it only applies for stuff like `x/10` or for `const` variables.  See [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46378104)